# Gift Memberships extension, missing gift codes

Tags: civimember, extension, gift-memberships

I'm on Civicrm 4.6.26 / wordpress. Trying out the Gift Memberships extension.

I have the purchase gift memberships priceset and contribution page.
I have the redeem gift membership priceset and contribution page.

My purchase gift membership payment completes and I get the Gift Membership Codes email, but with no codes.  Codes are also missing from the contribution record and the confirmation page.

The Contribution page setup has the priceset chosen on the Amounts tab.  The membership section is disabled.  I've tried it the other way also with the priceset chosen on the memberships tab.

Any ideas on what's going on? Or how I can troubleshoot?

Or any ideas to implement gift memberships other then with this extension for wordpress?